# Chrome расширение

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Подскажите, как в расширении получить запрос и ответ к сайту. Через chrome.webRequest удалось получить все кроме данных от сайта(заголовки получены). Хотелось бы и данные получить.

Comment: Можете написать более подробно или на примере что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Возьмите любую flash игрушку в вконтакте или других сетях, общающуюся со своим сервером по https. Обычно используется json или xml сообщения. Мне нужно получить данные передающиеся между игрой и ее сервером: что запросил клиент и что ответил сервер. Под firefox я такую штуку написал.

Comment: Тогда мне непонятно для чего Вам нужно расширение для хрома. В данном случае в самом деле достаточно обычного ajax запроса. Даже если вы работаете с расширением то Вам всеравно для того чтобы получить данные с сервера прийдется отправлять к нему запросы.

Comment: Расширение мне нужно для перехвата https запросов. По другому их никак не перехватить. Мне нужно получить данные не отправляя запросов. Все запросы делает сама игрушка. Повторный запрос окажет влияние на игру: продаст еще раз, купит еще раз... Это очевидный провал.
Насколько я понял ситуацию, сделать так как я хочу нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

достаточно [XMLHttpRequest](http://xmlhttprequest.ru) для этих целей

в permission указать адрес сайта к которому будет вестись запрос

сам код запроса:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.open("GET", адрес ссылки, true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    /*ответ от сервера получен*/
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var html = this.response;
        //а дальше творим с html, что хотим:
        // html.getDocumentById(), html.getElementsByTagName(), html.querySelector(), html.querySelectorAll()
        // и т.д
        //переменная html получает все свойства HTMLDocument
    }

}
xhr.send(null);
```

this.readyState, this.status - коды ответов от сервера. пример подходит если необходимо получить полноценный DOM-document, если текстовые данные, то меняйте xhr.responseType

Comment: XMLHttpRequest штука хорошая, но к сожалению я не могу послать повторный запрос. Требуется получить данные из имеющегося запроса.

Comment: какой еще повторный?

Comment: вешаете таймер, если через какое-то время ответ не приходит то делаете xhr.abort() и снова шлете и т.д.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest же заново загрузит страницу? У меня запрос меняющий содержимое сайта, поэтому я не могу посылать его снова.

Comment: Делаю синхронный запрос. Если не удается соединиться скрипт прекращает работу. alert() после send() не срабатывает. Как это исправить?

Comment: никак не исправить, синхоронный запрос всегда так будет себя вести. только если запихать синхронный запрос в webworker

Comment: Хрень какая-то. Мне нужно шапку установить в случае недоступности страницы, а оно перестает выполняться. Может это можно как исключениями перехватить?

Comment: модель javascript не позволяет таких манипуляций, любую докуменацию если почитать все настойчиво рекомендуют пользоваться асинхронными запросами. помогает иногда html5 webworker